# No setLayout() Method with JPanel object

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to apply gridBagLayout to my form and I create a JPanel object but setLayout() method not appear. Can anyone help please?

Path:

```
import javax.swing.*;

JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

---

Here is my full source code:
There is no error just Layout Manager is not working.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class CamInfo extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JLabel lb1, lbUsername, lbPassword;
    JTextField tfUsername, tfPassword;
    JButton btLogin, btSignup, btGuest;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    public CamInfo() {

        setSize(400,200);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); // no setLayout() method for p1

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        lb1 = new JLabel("Travelling Guide");
        lbUsername = new JLabel("Username");
        lbPassword = new JLabel("Password");

        tfUsername = new JTextField(10);
        tfPassword = new JTextField(10);

        btLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btSignup = new JButton("Sign up");
        btGuest = new JButton("Guest");

        addItem(p1, lbUsername, 0,0,1,1, GridBagConstraints.EAST);
        addItem(p1, lbPassword, 0,1,1,1, GridBagConstraints.EAST);

        addItem(p1, tfUsername, 1,0,2,1, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
        addItem(p1, tfPassword, 1,1,1,1, GridBagConstraints.WEST);

        add(p1);

        setVisible(true);

        btLogin.addActionListener(this);
        btSignup.addActionListener(this);
        btGuest.addActionListener(this);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public  static void main(String args[]){
        new CamInfo();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getSource() == btLogin){

        }

        if(ae.getSource() == btSignup){

        }

        if(ae.getSource() == btGuest){

        }

    }

    void addItem(JPanel p, JComponent c, int x, int y, int width, int height, int align){
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.gridx = x;
        gc.gridy = y;
        gc.gridwidth = width;
        gc.gridheight = height;
        gc.weightx = 100.0;
        gc.weighty = 100.0;
        gc.insets = new insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gc.anchor = align;
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        p.add(c, gc);
    }
}
```

---

Here is my full source code:
There is no error just Layout Manager is not working.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class CamInfo extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JLabel lb1, lbUsername, lbPassword;
    JTextField tfUsername, tfPassword;
    JButton btLogin, btSignup, btGuest;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    public CamInfo() {

        setSize(400,200);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); // no setLayout() method for p1

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        lb1 = new JLabel("Travelling Guide");
        lbUsername = new JLabel("Username");
        lbPassword = new JLabel("Password");

        tfUsername = new JTextField(10);
        tfPassword = new JTextField(10);

        btLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btSignup = new JButton("Sign up");
        btGuest = new JButton("Guest");

        addItem(p1, lbUsername, 0,0,1,1, GridBagConstraints.EAST);
        addItem(p1, lbPassword, 0,1,1,1, GridBagConstraints.EAST);

        addItem(p1, tfUsername, 1,0,2,1, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
        addItem(p1, tfPassword, 1,1,1,1, GridBagConstraints.WEST);

        add(p1);

        setVisible(true);

        btLogin.addActionListener(this);
        btSignup.addActionListener(this);
        btGuest.addActionListener(this);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public  static void main(String args[]){
        new CamInfo();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getSource() == btLogin){

        }

        if(ae.getSource() == btSignup){

        }

        if(ae.getSource() == btGuest){

        }

    }

    void addItem(JPanel p, JComponent c, int x, int y, int width, int height, int align){
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.gridx = x;
        gc.gridy = y;
        gc.gridwidth = width;
        gc.gridheight = height;
        gc.weightx = 100.0;
        gc.weighty = 100.0;
        gc.insets = new insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gc.anchor = align;
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        p.add(c, gc);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have your own class named `JPanel` that is confusing your compiler. Rename that class.

Comment: but for better help, post a more complete code post and the full error message. For all we know, you could be trying to call that method naked out in the class, and not in a method or a constructor.

Comment: I didn't have another JPanel class.

Comment: Please post any edits, including your "full source code" as an [edit] to your question. Don't post it as an answer since 1) it's not an answer, and 2) posting a non-answer might reduce your chances of getting a real answer, since others might see that the question has already been answered.

Comment: Also, define your problem. What do you mean by the method does not appear -- your question doesn't make sense since the JPanel *is* getting the GridBaglayout, and the layout is working.

Comment: Is it that you don't see your JButtons in the GUI? If so, it's because you never **add** them to the GUI

Answer (score 2):

Your JPanel p1 is getting the GridBagLayout just fine, but you don't see the buttons in the GUI because you never add them. For example you could add your buttons to their own JPanel, one that uses a GridLayout, and then add this to the 3rd row of your GUI, and they would show up fine:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CamInfo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel lb1, lbUsername, lbPassword;
    JTextField tfUsername, tfPassword;
    JButton btLogin, btSignup, btGuest;

    public CamInfo() {

        // setSize(400, 200);  // don't do this. pack() instead

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); // no setLayout() method for p1

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        lb1 = new JLabel("Travelling Guide");
        lbUsername = new JLabel("Username");
        lbPassword = new JLabel("Password");

        tfUsername = new JTextField(10);
        tfPassword = new JTextField(10);

        btLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btSignup = new JButton("Sign up");
        btGuest = new JButton("Guest");

        addItem(p1, lbUsername, 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST);
        addItem(p1, lbPassword, 0, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST);

        addItem(p1, tfUsername, 1, 0, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
        addItem(p1, tfPassword, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST);

        // can add the buttons to their own GridLayout using JPanel
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 5));
        buttonPanel.add(btLogin);
        buttonPanel.add(btSignup);
        buttonPanel.add(btGuest);

        // then add this JPanel to fill the 3rd row of your GUI
        addItem(p1, buttonPanel, 0, 2, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);

        add(p1);
        pack();  // do this instead of set size
        setVisible(true);

        btLogin.addActionListener(this);
        btSignup.addActionListener(this);
        btGuest.addActionListener(this);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new CamInfo();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == btLogin) {

        }

        if (ae.getSource() == btSignup) {

        }

        if (ae.getSource() == btGuest) {

        }

    }

    void addItem(JPanel p, JComponent c, int x, int y, int width, int height, int align) {
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.gridx = x;
        gc.gridy = y;
        gc.gridwidth = width;
        gc.gridheight = height;
        gc.weightx = 100.0;
        gc.weighty = 100.0;
        gc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gc.anchor = align;
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;  // this is better than NONE
        p.add(c, gc);
    }
}
```

This displays as:

[image]

Comment: @HerryBen: you're welcome, but you still haven't told us clearly what your problem was/is. Please edit your question and include this information, else the question and answer will not be helpful to future visitors.